# Removing spaces and newlines between tags in html (aka unformatting) in python

Tags: python, html, regex

An example:

```
<p> Hello</p>
<div>hgello</div>
<pre>
   code
    code
<pre>
```

turns in something like:

```
<p> Hello</p><div>hgello</div><pre>
    code
     code
<pre>
```

How to do this in python? I make also intensive use of < pre> tags so substituting all '\n' with '' is not an option.

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `re.sub(">\s*<","><","[here your html string]")`.

Maybe `string.replace(">\n",">")`, i.e. look for an enclosing bracket and a newline and remove the newline.

Comment: You should always use raw strings with regex, aka r'the-pattern'. In this case it doesn't matter, but I think it's good practice.

Answer (score 2):

I would choose to use the python regex:

```
string.replace(">\s+<","><")
```

Where the '\s' finds any whitespace character and the '+' after it shows it matches one or more whitespace characters. This removes the possibility of the replace replacing

```
<pre>
    code
     code
<pre>
```

with

```
<pre><pre>
```

More information about regular expressions can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html), [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/python.html) and [here](http://diveintopython.net/regular_expressions/street_addresses.html).

Comment: Just a nitpick: I think `string.replace` doesn't take regular expressions, does it?

Comment: Oops. Thanks @phimuemue. Instead use re.sub(regex, replacement, subject) where regex is the ">\s+<" and replacement is the "><"