# Constructing Django templates from strings within Python code

Tags: python, html, django

I'd like to test a custom filter I wrote in Django, `label_with_classes`. My basic approach is to instantiate a 'snippet' of my actual template using by instantiating a `django.template.Template` with a string, rendering it with some context, and asserting that the generated output is what I would expect.

I would also like to be able to write tags, etc. on new lines like I do in the actual template. The problem is that when I do this, lots of whitespaces appear in the rendered output.

Here is a test case so far:

```
from ..templatetags.label_with_classes import label_with_classes
from django.test import SimpleTestCase
from django.template import Context, Template


from ..forms.sessions import SessionForm


class CustomFilterTest(SimpleTestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        form = SessionForm(data={})

        template = Template("\
            {% load label_with_classes %}\
            {{ form.session_number|label_with_classes }}")
        context = Context({'form': form})

        output = template.render(context)
```

upon which I drop into the debugger using `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`. Here I see that `output` has lots of leading whitespaces:

```
ipdb> output
'                        <label class="invalid" for="id_session_number">Session number:</label>'
```

It seems like this whitespace comes from me writing on new lines in the string in the `Template()` constructor. However, in the actual HTML whitespaces between HTML tags are ignored.

Is there a way to 'write HTML within' Python so that I could directly copy-paste snippets from the actual HTML template into this test code?

**Update**

I've tried using `textwrap.dedent()`, but I still get some leading whitespaces. With the template constructed like so:

```
    template = Template(textwrap.dedent("\
        {% load label_with_classes %}\
        {{ form.session_number|label_with_classes }}"))
```

The `output` looks like

```
ipdb> output
'            <label class="invalid" for="id_session_number">Session number:</label>'
```

Although there are fewer whitespaces than before, they are still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just calling `strip()` on the output of `template.render()`:

```
output = template.render(context).strip()
```

This removes the leading (and trailing) whitespaces:

```
ipdb> output
'<label class="invalid" for="id_session_number">Session number:</label>'
```

In this case there is just one HTML tag (`<label>`); if there were more than one and I wanted to remove whitespaces between them, I could also use a regular expression to remove whitespaces between closing `>` and opening `<`s:

```
import re
output = re.sub(r'>\s*<', r'><', output)
```

as described in [Removing spaces and newlines between tags in html (aka unformatting) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093802/removing-spaces-and-newlines-between-tags-in-html-aka-unformatting-in-python).

**Update**

Considering this particular use case - a unit test - one can also use the [`assertHTMLEqual`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertHTMLEqual) method of Django's `TestCase` class, which asserts that two strings are equal based on HTML semantics. For example, the following test passes:

```
    output = template.render(context)
    self.assertHTMLEqual(output, '<label class="invalid" for="id_session_number">Session number:</label>')
```

even though I didn't call `strip()` on the `output`.

Answer (score 0):

There's this small trick I like to use in such cases:

```
html = "\
    {% load label_with_classes %}\
    {{ form.session_number|label_with_classes }}"

html = ' '.join(html.split())
template = Template(html)
```

It will remove all white spaces and between words/tags etc will include just one space. Which is very similar to the expected behaviour on HTML (more than one space is ignored).